# can anyone explain what are these functions doing

Tags: javascript

```
function deleteParentNodeOnClick() {
  for (var i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
    deleteButton[i].addEventListener("click", deleteNodeOnClick);
  }
}

function deleteNodeOnClick(e) {
  var trash = document.querySelectorAll("i");
  for (var ind = 0; ind < trash.length; ind++) {
    console.log(e);
    this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: The code makes little sense to me. The loop in `deleteNodeOnClick` never uses `ind`. It keeps removing the same grandparent node, not anything related to `trash`.

Comment: deleteParentNodeOnClick is adding a click listener to an array of delete buttons. deleteNodeOnClick is that event listener. It gets all <i> tags and deletes something else's grandparent. Without more context, I don't know what `this` refers to.

Comment: @CharlesBamford `this` is the clicked button.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was a jQuery thing and you needed event.target in vanillajs. Til

Comment: @CharlesBamford In fact, I suspect this code is the result of someone incorrectly translating jQuery to vanilla JS. They probably converted `$("i").each()` to a `for` loop. `.each()` binds `this` in the callback function, `for` doesn't do that in its body.